# iTextSharp (C#): Add text (over everything) at position

Tags: c#, wpf, text, itext, positioning

I'm trying to use iTextSharp in a WPF project to add text to existing PDFs over everything else and at a given point.  Basically the digital equivalent of writing on a paper document

I've tried multiple methods and nothing seems to actually write the text to the new PDF. My code is messy from testing various things (left in so I know what I've tried - yes, I'll be clearing it out after resolution), so I'll try to get all of the important lines.

```
var stream = new FileStream(targetFilePath, FileMode.Create);
var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
var target = new PdfCopy(doc, stream);

doc.Open();

var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);

foreach (var vm in Pages) // Cycles through pages in WPF object...
{
    var srcDoc = vm.DocTmpFName;

    if (Path.GetExtension(srcDoc).ToUpperInvariant() == ".PDF")
    {
        var reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(srcDoc);
        var page = reader.GetPageN(vm.Number);
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream);

        target.AddPage(target.GetImportedPage(reader, vm.Number));

        page.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(vm.Rotation % 360f));

        // Inside this 'foreach' loop is what isn't working.  The rest works fine.
        foreach(var str in vm.Strings) // str is a container class (just a string and two 'double' vars for positioning)
        {
            // This isn't writing to new PDF even though it gets run (verified with breakpoints)
            var contentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(vm.Number);

            contentByte.BeginText();
            contentByte.SetTextMatrix((float)str.X, (float)str.Y);
            contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 72f); //Making it stupid-big so I don't miss it
            contentByte.ShowText(str.String);
            contentByte.EndText();
        }

        target.FreeReader(reader);
        reader.Close();

    }
}

target.Close();
doc.Close();
stream.Close();
```

If you feel I've missed something let me know.  I tried to keep the context of the problem area, so hopefully it's not too horrible of a hack-job.

**- Edited to correct code -**

---

**Edit**

I renamed some variables to make it easier to discern what they're for. Also, I've included the new fixed (albeit buggy) code that adds text at a position - for anyone stumbling across this later. =)

### Working code after @mkl's answer:

```
var stream = new FileStream(targetFilePath, FileMode.Create);
var doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
var targetPdf = new PdfCopy(doc, stream);

doc.Open();

foreach (ViewModels.PageViewModel vm in document.Pages)
{
    var srcDocPath = FileIO.ToTempFileName(vm.DocName);

    // Copy pageDict from source...
    if (Path.GetExtension(srcDocPath).ToUpperInvariant() == ".PDF")
    {
        var srcReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(srcDocPath);
        var pageDict = srcReader.GetPageN(vm.Number);
        var importedPage = targetPdf.GetImportedPage(srcReader, vm.Number);
        var pageStamp = targetPdf.CreatePageStamp(importedPage);

        foreach(var str in vm.Strings)
        {
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pageStamp.GetOverContent(),
                iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
                new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(str.String),
                (float) str.X,
                // pdf-origin is bottom-left, not top-left
                (float)(importedPage.Height - str.Y),
                0);
        }

        pageDict.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(vm.Rotation % 360f));
        pageStamp.AlterContents();
        targetPdf.AddPage(importedPage);

        targetPdf.FreeReader(srcReader);
        srcReader.Close();
    }
}
targetPdf.Close();
doc.Close();
stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Your code has a number of issues some of which @Übercoder already addressed in his answer.*

Furthermore you have **a `PdfCopy` and multiple `PdfStamper` instances writing into the same stream**. This will result in utter chaos in the stream output. If you want to *stamp* pages you *copy*, you should use a `PdfCopy.PageStamp`, e.g. like this:

```
using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, OUTPUT_STREAM)) {
    document.Open();
    PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(r1);
    int n1 = reader1.NumberOfPages;
    PdfImportedPage page;
    PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; ) {
        page = copy.GetImportedPage(reader1, ++i);
        stamp = copy.CreatePageStamp(page);
        // CHANGE THE PAGE,
        // e.g. by manipulating stamp.GetOverContent()
        ...
        //
        stamp.AlterContents();
        copy.AddPage(page);
    }
}
```

*(excerpt from the official iTextSharp sample [ConcatenateStamp.cs](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/book/raw/master/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/ConcatenateStamp.cs))*

Comment: I'll try that out later today. This is potentially copying pages from multiple source PDFs, which is why I had multiple stampers. Does 'copy.CratePageStamp' not create a new instance?

Comment: @CheeseMo *Does 'copy.CratePageStamp' not create a new instance* - `PdfCopy.CreatePageStamp` creates a new `PageStamp`. But a `PageStamp` is *not* an independent `PdfStamper` but an object with similar capabilities built into the one copying process.

Comment: that did it!  Thanks for the reference link, too.  I edited my post to include the working code - elaborating on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You chould not close the reader inside the `foreach` loop. Nor (I suspect) should you do the `target.FreeReader` call:

```
foreach(var str in vm.Strings) // str is a container class (just a string and two 'double' vars for positioning)
{
    // This isn't writing to new PDF even though it gets run (verified with breakpoints)
    var contentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(vm.Number);

    contentByte.BeginText();
    contentByte.SetTextMatrix((float)str.X, (float)str.Y);
    contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 72f); //Making it stupid-big so I don't miss it
    contentByte.ShowText(str.String);
    contentByte.EndText();
}
//moved the next two lines out of the foreach loop
target.FreeReader(reader);
reader.Close();
```

The same aplies for these three lines:

```
target.Close();
doc.Close();
stream.Close();
```

They, too should be moved out of the `foreach (var vm in Pages)` loop that currently contains them.

Comment: You're correct. I must've messed it up when I copied lines over. I'll get my post corrected.